# How to draw a vertical line in Paraview Line Chart

Tags: plotting, paraview

I would like to insert a series of vertical lines to divide up a line chart. The figure below shows the chart so far, but instead of the orange diamonds I want vertical lines that go from top to bottom of the figure. What's the easiest/best way to do this?

Context: this is a trust-region optimization problem showing the parameter evolution, and I want to show at what points my low-fidelity model is being updated. The vertical position of the orange dots shows the parameter value at which the model was retrained, but I don't care about this information - I just want to show it everywhere vertically with a thin line.

[image: Current Line Chart]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would add an extra variable, that goes between the max and min of your other variables and only changes value when your method changes, and, thus, connects them as a sum of step functions. In some plotting packages, you can use NaN in between to plot nothing and only plot the vertical lines (MATLAB works like this). I don’t know if Paraview does.